# Convert IIFE module to something importable by RollupJS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iife, rollupjs

I am using RollupJS as a bundler, and it can read CommonJS (via a plugin) or ES6 modules. But this module seems to be in UMD format, and I am looking for a quick way I can edit it (without replacing a lot of lines) so that it is in commonJS or ES6 format.

What do folks suggest? I show the top and the bottom of a 5,000 line .js file.

```
@module vrlinkjs
**/
(function (mak) {

mak.MessageKindEnum = {
        Any : -1,
        Other : 0,
        AttributeUpdate : 1,
        Interaction : 2,
        Connect : 3,
        ObjectDeletion : 4
    };
/**
    Decodes AttributeUpdate messages into an EnvironmentalStateRepository object.
    @class EnvironmentalStateDecoder
    @constructor
    @augments StateDecoder
    @param {WebLVCConnection} webLVCConnection Connection to a WebLVC server
    **/
    mak.EnvironmentalStateDecoder = function(webLVCConnection) {
        mak.StateDecoder.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    mak.EnvironmentalStateDecoder.prototype = Object.create(mak.StateDecoder.prototype, {
        constructor : { value : mak.EnvironmentalStateDecoder },

        /**
        Decodes a AttributeUpdate message into an EntityStateRepository object.
        @method decode
        @param {Object} attributeUpdate WebLVC AttributeUpdate message
        @param {EntityStateRepository} stateRep State repository to be updated
        **/
        decode : {
            value : function( attributeUpdate, stateRep ) {

                // if(this.webLVCConnection.timeStampType == mak.TimeStampType.TimeStampAbsolute &&
                    // attributeUpdate.TimeStampType == mak.TimeStampType.TimeStampAbsolute) {
                // } else {
                    // stateRep.timeStampType = mak.TimeStampType.TimeStampRelative;
                // }
                stateRep.timeStampType = mak.TimeStampType.TimeStampRelative;

                var curTime = 0.0;
                // if (stateRep->timeStampType() == DtTimeStampAbsolute)
                // {
                // // Use timestamp as time of validity
                // curTime = pdu.guessTimeValid(myExConn->clock()->simTime());
                // }
                // else
                // {
                // // Use receive time as time of validity
                // curTime = myExConn->clock()->simTime();       
                // }
                curTime = this.webLVCConnection.clock.simTime;

                 if(attributeUpdate.ProcessIdentifier != undefined) { 
                    stateRep.entityIdentifier = attributeUpdate.EntityIdentifier;
                }
                if(attributeUpdate.Type != undefined) { 
                    stateRep.entityType = attributeUpdate.Type;
                }
                if(attributeUpdate.ObjectName != undefined) { 
                    stateRep.objectName = attributeUpdate.ObjectName;
                }
                if(attributeUpdate.GeometryRecords != undefined) {
                    stateRep.GeometryRecords = attributeUpdate.GeometryRecords;
                }
                if(attributeUpdate.EnvObjData != undefined) {
                   if(attributeUpdate.EnvObjData.VrfObjName != undefined) {
                      stateRep.marking = attributeUpdate.EnvObjData.VrfObjName;
                   }
                }
            }
        }           
    });
.....

} (this.mak = this.mak || {}));
```

---

**UPDATE**

I used the ES6 module solution from estus (below), which I really like. It solved the rollup bunding issue, but there is still a runtime error.

But there is a little more that needs to be done. I am getting this error with chrome. I have two varients of the HTML main.html file, one uses the bundle and the other just imports my es6 modules. The error occurs even when I am not using rollup and creating and using the bundle.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property objectName of [object Object] which has only a getter
    at mak$1.ReflectedEntity.mak$1.ReflectedObject [as constructor] (vrlink.mjs:818)
    at new mak$1.ReflectedEntity (vrlink.mjs:903)
    at mak$1.ReflectedEntityList.value (vrlink.mjs:1358)
    at mak$1.WebLVCMessageCallbackManager.<anonymous> (vrlink.mjs:1155)
    at mak$1.WebLVCMessageCallbackManager.processMessage (vrlink.mjs:1745)
    at mak$1.WebLVCConnection.drainInput (vrlink.mjs:2139)
    at SimLink.tick (SimLink.js:34)
```

This seems to be the offender when converting from IIFE modules to ES6. It says that there is no setter.

The code is not my creation, but it seemed like it should not have be a major effort to convert IIFE to ES6. The offending snippet is:

```
mak.VrfBackendStateRepository = function (objectName) {

/**
Unique string identifying entity
@property objectName 
@type String
**/
this.objectName = objectName;   //error generated on this line!
```

If you are wondering what **this** is, it is a object called mak.webLVConnection, which is created by this function in the IIFE code:

```
/**
    Represents a connection to a WebLVC server.
    clientName and port are required.  webLVCVersion is optional (current version
    supported by the WebLVC server will be in effect).  serverLocation is optional
    ( websocket connection will be made to the host servering the javascript )
    @class WebLVCConnection 
    @constructor
    @param {String} clientName String representing name of the client federate
    @param {Number} port Websocket port number
    @param {Number} webLVCVersion WebLVC version number
    @param {String} serverLocation Hostname of websocket server
    **/
mak.WebLVCConnection = function (clientName, port, webLVCVersion, serverLocation, url) {

    var self = this;

    if (clientName == undefined) {
        throw new Error("clientName not specified");
    }
    if (!(typeof clientName == "string" && clientName.length > 0)) {
        throw new Error("Invalid ClientName specified");
    }
    if (port == undefined) {
        throw new Error("Port not specified");
    }
    if (url == undefined) {
        url = "/ws";
    }

    var websocket;
    if (serverLocation == undefined) {
        if (location.hostname) {
            websocket = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.hostname + ":" + port + url);
        }
        else {
            websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:" + port + "/ws");
        }
    }
    else {
        websocket = new WebSocket("ws://" + serverLocation + ":" + port + url);
    }

    /**
    Websocket connected to a WebLVC server.
    @property websocket
    @type WebSocket
    **/
    this.websocket = websocket;

    /**
    DIS/RPR-style identifier, used to generate new unique IDs for entities simulated
    through this connection.   Array of 3 numbers [site ID, host ID, entity number].
    @property currentId
    @type Array
    **/
    this.currentId = [1, 1, 0];

    /**
    Manages registration and invoking of message callbacks.
    @property webLVCMessageCallbackManager
    @type WebLVCMessageCallbackManager
    **/
    this.webLVCMessageCallbackManager = new mak.WebLVCMessageCallbackManager();

    /**
    Simulation clock
    @property clock
    @type Clock
    **/
    this.clock = new mak.Clock();

    /**
    Indicates whether timestamping is relative or absolute
    (mak.TimeStampType.TimeStampRelative or 
    mak.TimeStampType.TimeStampAbsolute).
    @property {Number} timeStampType
    **/
    this.timeStampType = mak.TimeStampType.TimeStampRelative;

    /**
    List of incoming messages.  When messages are received, they are placed
    in this queue.  The drainInput() member function must be called regularly
    to remove and process messages in this queue.
    @property {Array} messageQueue
    **/
    this.messageQueue = new Array();

    /**
    Callback function invoked on receipt of a message.  Calls 
    webLVCMessageCallbackManager.processMessage().
    @method processMessage
    @private
    **/
    this.processMessage = this.webLVCMessageCallbackManager.processMessage.bind(this.webLVCMessageCallbackManager);

    /**
    Callback function invoked when websocket connection is opened.  Sends
    the initial WebLVC connect message.
    @method onopen
    @private
    **/
    this.websocket.onopen = function () {
        var connectMessage = {
            MessageKind: mak.MessageKindEnum.Connect,
            ClientName: clientName
        }

        if (webLVCVersion != undefined) {
            connectMessage.WebLVCVersion = webLVCVersion;
        }

        if (self.websocket.readyState == 1) {
            self.websocket.send(JSON.stringify(connectMessage));
        }
    };

    /**
    Callback function invoked when a WebLVC message is received.  Parses the
    the JSON message data and passes the resulting object to processMessage.
    @method onmessage
    @event {Object} JSON message
    @private
    **/
    this.websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        //just in case
        if (event.data == "ping")
            return;

        var message = JSON.parse(event.data);
        if (message != null) {
            self.messageQueue.push(message);
        } else {
            console.warn("onmessage - null message received");
        }
    };

    /**
    Callback function invoked when the websocket is closed.
    @method onclose
    @private
    **/
    this.websocket.onclose = function () {
        console.debug("In websocket.onclose");
    };

    /**
    Callback function invoked when an error in the websocket is detected.
    Sends warning to console.
    @method onerror
    @private
    **/
    this.websocket.onerror = function () {
        console.log("websocket onerror");
    };

    this.isOk = function () {
        return this.websocket.readyState == 1;
    }
};

mak.WebLVCConnection.prototype = {

    constructor: mak.WebLVCConnection,

    /**
    Set the DIS/RPR-style application ID.
    @method set applicationId
    @param {Array} applicationId Array of 2 integers [site ID, host ID].
    **/
    set applicationId(applicationId) {
        this.currentId[0] = applicationId[0];
        this.currentId[1] = applicationId[1];
        this.currentId[2] = 0;
    },

    /**
    Returns next available DIS/RPR-style entity ID.
    @method nextId
    @return {Array} Array of 3 integers [site ID, host ID, entity number].
    **/
    get nextId() {
        this.currentId[2]++;
        return this.currentId;
    },

    /**
    Register callback function for a given kind of message.
    @method addMessageCallback
    @param {Number} messageKind WebLVC MessageKind
    @param callback Function to be invoked
    **/
    addMessageCallback: function (messageKind, callback) {
        this.webLVCMessageCallbackManager.addMessageCallback(messageKind, callback);
    },

    /**
    De-register callback function for a given kind of message.
    @method removeMessageCallback
    @param messageKind WebLVC MessageKind
    @param callback Function to be invoked
    **/
    removeMessageCallback: function (messageKind, callback) {
        this.webLVCMessageCallbackManager.removeMessageCallback(messageKind, callback);
    },

    /**
    Send a WebLVC message to the server.
    @method send
    @param {Object} message
    **/
    send: function (message) {
        try {
            if (this.websocket.readyState == 1) {
                this.websocket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
            }
        } catch (exception) {
            console.log("Error sending on websocket - exception: " + exception);
        }
    },

    /**
    Send a time-stamped WebLVC message to the server.
    @method sendStamped
    @param {Object} message
    **/
    sendStamped: function (message) {
        // Timestamp is hex string
        var timeStamp = this.currentTimeForStamping().toString(16);
        //message.TimeStamp = ""; // timeStamp;

        this.send(message);
    },

    /**
    Get the current simulation time for a time stamp.
    @method currentTimeForStamping
    @return {Number} Simulation time in seconds.
    **/
    currentTimeForStamping: function () {
        if (this.timeStampType == mak.TimeStampType.TimeStampAbsolute) {
            return this.clock.simTime();
        }
        else {
            return this.clock.absRealTime();
        }
    },

    /**
    Iterate through message queue, calling processMessage() and then
    removing each message.  Should be called regularly from your 
    application.
    @method drainInput
    **/
    drainInput: function () {
        var message;

        while (this.messageQueue.length > 0) {
            message = this.messageQueue.shift();
            this.processMessage(message);
        }
    },

    /**
    Closes the websocket connection.  Calls the destroy method on its 
    WebLVCMessageCallbackManager data member.
    @method destroy
    **/
    destroy: function () {
        console.debug("In WebLVCConnection.destroy");
        this.webLVCMessageCallbackManager.destroy();
        this.websocket.close();
    }
};
```

Comment: @estus What about changing the title to convert IIFE module to ES6, since rollup is really not vital, and that will make this solution more general for folks looking for help?

Comment: I guess it will work.

Answer (score 2):

UMD modules, by definition, are CommonJS. The code above is just IIFE and relies on `mak` global.

IIFE wrapper function can be replaced with default or named ES module export:

```
const mak = {};

mak.MessageKindEnum = { ... };
...

export default mak;
```

Or with CommonJS export:

```
const mak = {};

mak.MessageKindEnum = { ... };
...

module.exports = mak;
```

Comment: I really like this. I went with the first suggestion (ES6 modules), so that I could also use it without creating a bundle (rollup). I wrote my modules so that the could work either way, in a bundle or as es6 imports per .mjs file. See update for what is still blocking the IIFE -> ES6 converstion

Comment: I see. This is a different issue. This depends on how you use VrfBackendStateRepository and what you expect `this` to be in `this.objectName`.

Comment: I provided the explanation of what *this* is and the function that is responsible for its creation. I suspect that since it is a function, and es6 is strict, you may not be able to set properties. is that correct?

Comment: It doesn't really explain what's `this` because `this` is dynamic and depends on how the function is called. The code is hard to follow, so I'm not sure what exactly is going on there. No, the props can be set in strict mode. `Cannot set property` could be thrown when a prop is read-only descriptor. And this would be a problem.

Comment: I agree the code is hard to follow, (I could repeat that I did not write it). But I have the advantage of the debugger. **this** is always an instance of mak.WebLVCConnection, which is a function defined by: mak.WebLVCConnection.prototype = {  constructor: mak.WebLVCConnection, ...  the actual function (and its returned value when it is called is : mak.WebLVCConnection = function (clientName, port, webLVCVersion, serverLocation, url) { ..}}, does that help @estus?

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't. `Cannot set property objectName` means that `objectName` property was defined as read-only (with Object.defineProperty) at some point at *some object*, and in your code there's no clues. Since `this` context is one of the few things that can be affected by module conversion and also primary suspect, I would assume that `this` went wrong at some place, and since it's complex problem, it's impossible to say if it's really the case.

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Getter_only) explains the said error. Also make sure that you're using the module the same way as before. If you previously used it like `new mak.WebLVCConnection()` and now you're destructuring module members and use them like `new WebLVCConnection()` (or vice versa), this can affect things in unpredictable way - primarily `this` context. Did you also try to use the code from another answer? The result should be same, but if it differs, this could be a clue.

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```js
(function (mak) {
  ...
}(module.exports));

// instead of 
// } (this.mak = this.mak || {}));
```

Comment: might the script inside be buggy?

Comment: no, i was using the IIFE with no problems - when I include it in the html with a script tag:       <!-- <script src="libs/vrlink.js"></script> -->

Comment: @Dr.YSG This way it runs in loose mode and `this` may refer to `window` in some places. It won't be so in modular environment.

Comment: @estus well is is not a window. It is a function. see the above edits to the update.